# Node.js and high amount of watchers with fs

Tags: node.js, file-watcher

I'm using file system native library of nodejs, but i have problems with fs.watch, high amount of watchers is open, and sometimes node returns ENOSPC error, i localize the problem with linux kernel to open watchers and find that the dropbox app was eating a lot of watchers. 
My question is, if you know another file system libraries for node that works fine with the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the max user watches using:

```
echo 10000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```